# Spring Cloud Gateway Route URL pattern configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm have implemented Spring Cloud Gateway with Eureka discovery service, everything works fine but I have seen something that I don't know how to deal with when I write the URL and if I don't put a / at the end of the URL the gateway redirects to the app directly using its actual URL (registered in Eureka).

For example:

- https://example.com/bar  redirect to the app URL (http://example.app.url.com:8010/bar/)
- https://example.com/bar/ works as expected (it maintain the actual gateway URL)

Is there a configuration to avoid the first situation?

My configuration is the following:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: bar-service
          uri: lb://BAR-SERVICE/
          predicates:
            - Path=/bar/**
        - id: other-service
          uri: lb://OTHER-SERVICE/
          predicates:
            - Path=/OTHER/**
```

Additional information:

- I have a controller in every app that has '/' as an entry point (home page)
- I can use java configuration instead if necessary

Any advice will be appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use RewritePath in gateway configuration. The below is sample and hope it helpful to you.

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: bar-service
          uri: lb://BAR-SERVICE/
          predicates:
            - Path=/bar/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/bar(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

Comment: Thanks!! works like a charm! I ended with the following 
- RewritePath=/bar(?<segment>.*), /bar/$\{segment}